# Reusable Linq expression (to be passed to multiple .Where clauses in different parts of project)

Tags: c#, linq

I have the following linq query.

```
 var entities = await _context.Events
                .Include(x => x.Category)
                .Include(x => x.Owner)
                .Where(x =>
                    x.OwnerId == request.OwnerId && (
                        x.DateType == 1 && x.EndDateTimeUtc >= DateTime.UtcNow ||
                        x.DateType == 2 && x.Month >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.DateType == 3 && x.Quarter >= quarter && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year
                    ))
                .ToListAsync(cancellationToken);
```

I would like the expression in the .Where clause to be a function/variable that I can have it setup somewhere else and simple pass it into the where clauses.  I have multiple queries that require these very specific conditions so I would like to create it in one place and pass it around instead of having to copy and past.

The function I need to create needs to accept 2 parameters (one for request.OwnerId and one for Quarter) the rest are generated from dates/db fields

NOTE: part of the query is based a specific field, multiple other conditions only apply if DateType is a specific number  (1-3)

Comment: Have you looked at [`Expression`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.expressions.expression?view=netcore-3.1) class?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could create an extension method for `IQueryable<Event>` like this:

```
public static class EventExtension
{
  public static IQueryable<Event> GetFiltered(this IQueryable<Event> query, Int32 ownerId, Int32 quarter)
  {
    return query.Where(x =>
      x.OwnerId == ownerId && (
        x.DateType == 1 && x.EndDateTimeUtc >= DateTime.UtcNow ||
        x.DateType == 2 && x.Month >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
        x.DateType == 3 && x.Quarter >= quarter && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year
      ));
  }
}
```

Then simply call it from everywhere with

```
var entities = await _context.Events
     .Include(x => x.Category)
     .Include(x => x.Owner)
     .GetFiltered(request.ownerId, request.quarter)
```

Comment: this is exactly what I would be looking for if i could get it compiled https://imgur.com/a/dpN9kBd for list of errors, when i hover over this part of the code `GetFiltered<Event>` it says "This parameter 'Event' hides class  'Event'

Comment: Ok, there seems to be a conflict with the built in Event class and your entity Event class. Maybe try adding a namespace to Your.Project.Data.Event i.e.

Comment: I added a picture to the comment above that shows all the errors I am getting, should show the code (both my class and your extension) to show that how I have it setup.  Here is the picture of the errors https://imgur.com/a/dpN9kBd

Comment: `GetFiltered<Event>(...)` -> `GetFiltered(..)`

Answer (score 1):

you can use IQueryable like this

```
interface IFilter {
    IQueryable<Events> Filter(IQueryable<Events> query, Request request)
}

public class SpecificFilter : IFilter {
    public IQueryable<Events> Filter(IQueryable<Events> query, Request request)
    {
        if(request.ById) {
           query = query.Where(event => event.Id == request.Id);
        }
        return query;
    }
}
```

so you can have list of IFilter and apply them to your query

```
var query = _context.Events
    .Include(x => x.Category)
    .Include(x => x.Owner);
foreach(var filter in filterList) {
    query = filter.Filter(query, request);
}
var entities = await query;
```

Comment: this will work perfect as well, the extension method made it really easy. So thank you for the reply, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to [@TWP](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13488486/twp)'s and [Radik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/943792/radik)'s answers you also can do something like this:

```
var ownerId =  request.OwnerId;
var quater = ...;
Expression<Func<Event, bool>> predicate = x =>
                    x.OwnerId == ownerId && (
                        x.DateType == 1 && x.EndDateTimeUtc >= DateTime.UtcNow ||
                        x.DateType == 2 && x.Month >= DateTime.UtcNow.Month && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.DateType == 3 && x.Quarter >= quarter && x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year ||
                        x.Year >= DateTime.UtcNow.Year
                    )
```

And pass it like this `_context.Events.Where(predicate)`. You can extract expression creation to a separate method.

Comment: this will work perfect as well, the extension method made it really easy. So thank you for the reply, really appreciate it.

Comment: NP, glad it helped.